# Will not allow me to install playonlinux! Says I have 'held broken packages

Tags: apt, software-installation, playonlinux

When I try to download 'playonlinux' I get:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 playonlinux : Depends: icoutils but it is not installable
               Depends: curl but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

And I also can't install literally anything else.

Comment: What exactly did you tried? What leads to that error? What is the output of `sudo apt-get check`.

Answer (score -2):

First make sure you have wine windows loader installed play on linux relies on it
open your terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) type the following:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wine1.7   hit Y when prompt

sudo apt-get install winetricks
```

Install Synaptic Package Manager and once installed open in authorization mode. Once open click on custom filters, then broken, there should never be anything in that list… Click all packages in that list, set them for install and hit apply. Try again with your install of Play on Linux 
if you cannot through software center terminal it again type:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

Hit <kbd>Y</kbd> when prompted.

then open it

if this doesn't help I'm sorry that question may be a little over my head… when a package is broken it is places in that list

-Thamas

PS the Linux systems are great once you learn to use them and learn to get around on them. I used windows for years and finally started to use Ubuntu and would never go back. You can get a virtual windows on virtual box and you can use wine for a lot of games.

Comment: Why does he need to add more repositories if the ones included are giving problems?

Comment: if he can't open his software manager he can't instal wine or winetricks so he needs ppa to install it into terminal or it will not work.. least hasnt for me if you know a faster way please don't be afraid to add